# How to get the values for the graph of confidence limit for the exceedance fraction vs z-value?

Tags: confidence-interval, lognormal-distribution

I am working on an application for a team of industrial hygienists and I need to create a lookup function for the confidence limit for the exceedance fraction. I found what I need from this book: ["Occupational Exposure Assessment for Air Contaminants"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=2cgbek0qDrgC&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247) on page 247

The graph I need is this:
[image: Confidence limits for the exceedance fraction vs Calculated Z-value]

But its a JPEG graph and I need to write code to look up a value for example UCL(1.706,15) = 0.85 I can trace it on the graph and find the value but if I want this in code I can't do it because I cant find the formula or table of values to generate this graph.

I am looking for the formula or even a table for the data in this graph that I can put into a matrix in code and look it up.